# unable to get text of other textview in android?

Tags: java, android, textview

I am having a dynamic table in which I have created lots of `textview` dynamically... actually I having one row in which I have 3 `textview`... in this one of them contains unique id but other's `textview` value repeats around the table... therefore on the click of other `textview` I need text from unique `textview`.... so please suggest some thing like getting text from the neighbor `textview`... line through which I am able to get text from the `textview` is following.

```
((TextView)v).getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating dynamic `TextViews` assign a reference to the unique `TextView` as a tag using `setTag` to each of them.

```
TextView uniqueTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.unique_id);
TextView neighbourView = new TextView();
neighbourView.setTag(uniqueTextView);
```

You can later get the reference back using `getTag`

```
public void onTextViewClick(TextView view) {
    TextView uniqueTextView = (TextView)view.getTag();
    String text = uniqueTextView.getText().toString();    
}
```